# HTTP Request with Body using PATCH in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, rest, http, patch

I'm trying to send a Patch request with a serialized JSON Body.

For some reason the server is not able to receive the body properly. I have a feeling that there seems to be a problem with the PATCH method in combination with the http request body.

```
    let sessionConfig = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: sessionConfig, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: nil)

    var URL = B2MFetcher.urlForBooking(event.unique, bookingID: booking.unique)
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL)
    request.HTTPMethod = "PATCH"

    // Headers
    println(token)
    request.addValue(token, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.addValue("gzip, identity", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept-Encoding")

    // JSON Body
    let bodyObject = [
        "op": "cancel"
    ]
    var jsonError: NSError?
    request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(bodyObject, options: nil, error: &jsonError)

    /* Start a new Task */
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data : NSData!, response : NSURLResponse!, error : NSError!) -> Void in
        completion(data: data, response:response , error: error)
    })
    task.resume()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try to add a Content-Type header to the request:

```
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```

or use one of the other JSON Content-Type formats described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/what-is-the-correct-json-content-type).

I tested it with an ExpressJS server and without the Content-Type header the server got an empty body, but with a Content-Type header it worked well.

Answer (score 3):

in swift 3/4 :

```
 let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "http://XXX/xx/xxx/xx")! as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "PATCH"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        do{

           let json: [String: Any] = ["status": "test"]
           let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)
            request.httpBody = jsonData
            print("jsonData: ", String(data: request.httpBody!, encoding: .utf8) ?? "no body data")
        } catch {
            print("ERROR")
        }

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
            data, response, error in

            if error != nil {
                print("error=\(error)")
                completion(false)
                return
            }

            let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding:            String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
            print("responseString = \(responseString)")
            completion(true)
            return
        }
        task.resume()
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple Way to use patch without using `HTTPBody`

If you want to just use patch, you just need to change the value of the name of a specific user then it will be like:

```
let myurl = URL(string: "https://gorest.co.in/public-api/users/"+"\(id)?"+"name=abc")!

var request = URLRequest(url:myurl)
request.addValue("Bearer yourAuthorizationToken",forHTTPHeaderField:"Authorization")
request.httpMethod = "PATCH"

let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request)
dataTask.resume()
```

Note: here `"id"` will be `userId`